# A python package cannot be imported although pip3 show find it

Tags: python-3.x, mecab

I am troubled by an error saying an installed package is not found:

```
>>> import Mecab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Mecab'
```

I have tried install it from running the setup.py or from pip.

Below is the result of show:

```
labmanager@testUiServer:~/mecab-python3-0.996.1$ pip3 show mecab-python3
Name: mecab-python3
Version: 0.996.1
Summary: python wrapper for mecab: Morphological Analysis engine
Home-page: https://github.com/SamuraiT/mecab-python3
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/labmanager/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

I get this warning when running pip3 install mecab-python3. Wondering whether it is relevant.

The directory '/home/labmanager/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/labmanager/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You most probably have more than one Python interpreter installed, and `pip3` my not point to the same interpreter whose REPL you used. Compare the output of `which pip3` to the output of `which <python_intertpreter_you_used>`

Answer (score 0):

In code the package is called `MeCab`, not `Mecab`. So your code should look like this:

```
import MeCab
```

If that doesn't work, as the commenter mentioned you might have multiple pip installations or something.